# knockoutjs remove click binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I use knockoutjs and have a button (id='enter') with a click binding:

```
<input id="enter" type="button" value="Enter" data-bind="click: function(data,event) { console.log('do something'); console.log('do something more');}"/>
```

If I click the button "do something" and "do something more" is logged on the console.

How can I update the click binding, e.g. set a now binding? So that the click
of the button invokes another actions?

This doesnt work:

```
var enterButton = document.getElementById('enter');
var newClickBind = "click: function(data,event) { console.log('muh'); }";
enterButton.setAttribute('data-bind',newClickBind);
```

Thanks and regards

Comment: do you have a view model?

Comment: Don't.  Make the first click update state within your viewmodel instead, so that the next time it's clicked, it's the model itself that knows to do something different. (@indubitablee makes a good point, you _do_ have a viewmodel, right?)

Comment: This seems like total abuse of Knockout and MVVM in general. You need to elaborate more on what you're trying to achieve and perhaps show your current view-model too.

Comment: Yes, I have a view model...

Comment: My model simulates a buffer. I can add/remove elements from the buffer and the view is updated. The action which is done on "Enter click" depends on previous clicked buttons which change the buffer content. E.g. if button1 is clicked and the buffer is after that button1 action empty enter press causes new action1. If button1 is clicked and the buffer is not empty the click binding should not change

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is make an observable that holds a function, which you can change based on the state of things in your form. The `click` would get bound to *an invocation of* that observable.

```js
function thing1() {
  vm.output('thing 1');
}

function thing2() {
  vm.output('thing 2');
}

function thing3() {
  vm.output('thing 3');
}
var vm = {
  dynamicFunction: ko.observable(thing1),
  changeIt: function() {
    console.debug("Whatever");
    if (vm.dynamicFunction() == thing3) {
      vm.dynamicFunction(thing2);
    } else {
      vm.dynamicFunction(thing3);
    }
  },
  output: ko.observable('')
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Run" data-bind="click: dynamicFunction()" />
<input type="button" value="Switch" data-bind="click: changeIt" />
<div data-bind="text:output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should put all the logic of the `click` binding inside the viewModel. below is the VM function equivalent of your inline `click` binding

```js
// Here's my data model
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.clickFunction = function(data, event) {
     console.log('do something');
        console.log('do something else');
        console.log(data, event);
    };
};
 
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input id="enter" type="button" value="Enter" data-bind="click: function() { clickFunction($data, event); }"/>
```

**EDIT:** changing the click event based on other events

```js
// Here's my data model
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.action = ko.observable('doNothing');
    
    this.setDoSomething = function() {
     this.action('doSomething');
    };
    
    this.setDoSomethingElse = function() {
     this.action('doSomethingElse');
    };
    
    this.clickFunction = function() {
     if (this.action() == 'doSomething') {
         doSomething();
        }
        else if (this.action() == 'doSomethingElse') {
         doSomethingElse();
        }
        else {
         this.action('doNothing');
        }
    };
    
    function doSomething() {
     console.log('do something');
    }
    
    function doSomethingElse() {     
        console.log('do something else');
    }
};
 
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<button data-bind="click: setDoSomething">Make it Do something</button><br/>
<button data-bind="click: setDoSomethingElse">Make it Do something else</button><br/>
<br/><br/>
<input id="enter" type="button" value="Enter" data-bind="click: clickFunction"/><br/>
clicking enter will <div data-bind="text: action"></div>
```

Comment: My model simulates a buffer. I can add/remove elements from the buffer and the view is updated. The action which is done on "Enter click" depends on previous clicked buttons which change the buffer content. E.g. if button1 is clicked and the buffer is after that button1 action empty enter press causes new action1. If button1 is clicked and the buffer is not empty the click binding should not change

Comment: @knowledge check out the edit. i used other buttons to change the functionality of the enter `click` event

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ko.computed that returns to the click bind the function that needs to be executed, see the example:

```js
function AppViewModel() {
    
    this.choosenAction = ko.observable("1");
    var action1 = function(){
        console.log("Action 1 Done!!!")
    };
    
    var action2 = function(){
        console.log("Action 2 Done!!!")
    };
    
    this.onClickTest = ko.computed(function(){
        if(+this.choosenAction()===1)
            return action1;
        else
            return action2;
    },this);
    

}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<label for="act1"> Action 1 </label>
<input type="radio" id="act1" name="action" value="1" data-bind="checked: choosenAction"/>
<label for="act2"> Action 2 </label>
<input type="radio" id="act2" name="action" value="2" data-bind="checked: choosenAction"/>
</br>
</br>
<button data-bind="click: onClickTest()">Teste</button>
```

look that the function to be executed depends on the action choosed.